# Rails Tutorial Chapter 11 error "uninitialized constant User::Relationships"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, railstutorial.org

I have consistently been receiving the error

```
   uninitialized constant User::Relationships
```

When working through chapter 11 of the rails tutorial.

Here is the full error when I try to access the home page while logged in in my browser.

```
    Extracted source (around line #11):

8:          </a>
9:          <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
10:         <strong id="followers" class="stat">
11:             <%= @user.followers.count %>
12:         </strong>
13:         followers
14:     </a>
```

I have gone through the chapter multiple times and checked every line of code, but sometimes your eyes play tricks on you so here is the rest of the code

users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password

has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy 
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed 
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               class_name: "Relationships",
                               dependent:   :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase}
before_save :create_remember_token

validates :name, presence:true, length: { maximum: 50 }

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6}
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

def feed
  Micropost.where("user_id =?", id)
end

def following?(other_user)
  relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
end

def follow!(other_user)
  relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
end

def unfollow!(other_user)
  relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
end

private
  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

end
```

This is the class itself

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

This is how it is in the tutorial... I added :follower_id back in just in case and it still didn't work.

And I also have a relationship_controller built.

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :signed_in_user

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:follower_id])
  current_user.follow!(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
  current_user.unfollow!(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    fromat.js
  end
end
```

end

And in routes...

```
 resources :users do
   member do
     get :following, :followers
   end
 end
```

The page where the error is happening looks like this:

```
<% @user ||= current_user %>
<div class = "stats">
<a href ="<%= following_user_path(@user)%>">
    <strong id="following" class="stat">
        <%= @user.followed_users.count %>
    </strong>
    following
</a>
<a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="followers" class="stat">
        <%= @user.followers.count %>
    </strong>
    followers
</a>
</div>
```

The first part of the code before the second  block works perfectly when I removed the second part.  It is just the "followers" relationship is not getting set up for some reason.  I played around with it in the console and it wasn't calling, whereas user.followed_users does work.  I have been playing with this for four hours, have dropped the table and rebuilt it and I can't get it to work.

I tried looking on stack overflow before and found this:

[Ruby error (uninitialized constant User::Relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304421/ruby-error-uninitialized-constant-userrelationship)

But none of the solutions there helped.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a typo:

```
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                 class_name: "Relationships",
```

Change the last bit to `class_name: "Relationship"`.